# OwlCarousel2 stage padding magnific popup issue

Tags: css, owl-carousel, magnific-popup, console.log

I am using the owlcarousel2 plugin, and when clicking on an item I launch a magnificpopup instance.

I make use of stage padding on the carousel, which is an option to add padding left and right so that the first and last images are partly visible.

This works fine without images, but when using images in the carousel and a popup is launched from the last one and then closed the carousel shifts slightly and the last item becomes completely visible and the first item, is hidden.

I can reproduce in chrome and ie:

Without images https://jsfiddle.net/o1xu7xnt/6/ (works fine)

with images https://jsfiddle.net/o1xu7xnt/7/ (shifts content on popup close, click last image)

```
<script>
  console.log('please see my js-fiddles');
<script>
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and was wondering if someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item * {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zutfq80h/

Comment: Thanks, I've taken a look  and the issue is still reproducible in your example